# Asking whether I can apply for a health insurance with the link below

Tags: international-travel, health, insurance

I would like to ask whether I can really get a travel insurance by simply fill the format here in the link below, receive a receipt via e-mail certifying the purchase of the insurance and traveling worry-free, or whether it's a lie.

https://www.allianz-assistance.it/promo-care

The link is in Italian, but I hope to give you the Idea of how it's supposed to work and get an answer about whether it'll work.

Comment: Do you not have travel insurance included with your home insurance or credit card?

Comment: No, but what do they have to do with what I'm asking?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder, having a combination of travel insurance is not as usual as you imply by this remark.

Comment: "and traveling worry-free" Note that travel insurance comes with very specific legal language about what it does and doesn't cover, and you can expect the insurance company to refuse to pay claims that fall outside the exact scope of what the policy covers. The details depend on the insurance company and the policy you choose. Since traveling "worry-free" is important to you, I'd encourage you to read the full legal policy carefully so you understand exactly under what circumstances they'll pay claims.

Answer (score 1):

[Allianz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allianz) is a multi-national insurance company. The page you present solicits enrollment in travel insurance from Allianz in Italy. There's a bit more to it than just filling out the "card" on the first page.

When one fills out the card, one is taken to another page, where one must choose various kinds of coverage, or decline those coverages. Finally, the customer must actually pay for the policy. Standard practice would be to do so using a credit card.

After the customer fills out all the requested fields on the various web pages, and makes the credit card payment, the insurance will be in force **for the calendar term specified and the coverage(s) selected**. Allianz may well not even send you an enrollment card, but only provide the possibility of printing out a confirmation page.

Finally, Allianz is far from alone in this field: many, many companies sell travel-related insurance of many types. Make sure you read all the pages to understand what might be covered, and what might be excluded.

Many buy insurance; many travel without it. Whether this is "worry-free" is a matter of opinion for you alone.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as far as I've been told, this one is the only one (if not, one of the few) that pays directly the expenses in case of need, and does not require to pay in advance and then receiving a refund.

Comment: @abdul I don't know, I don't read Italian (Google Chrome was helpful) and don't know how Allianz' policy works. You'll have to examine various companies' offerings to see if their policies operate as you wish. I'll also suggest that you're now asking a new question about how policies are administered; you should therefore post a wholly-new question about this, not ask about it in Comments.

Comment: I'm not asking about various types of insurance, but about this one only and I asked whether a confirmation page will be useful to present at a hospital in case of need.  This is the only thing I asked.

Comment: Don't take offense, @abdul, but you did not ask that. In your question, there is no mention of presenting a confirmation page to a medical facility. You may have been thinking of that, but you wrote a different question about procuring an insurance policy.

Comment: Neither did I ask which types of assurances I should opt for.

Comment: I didn't ask directly, but from "worry-free" it should be understandable.

Comment: That was not clear. What is "worry-free" for you may be wholly different for other travelers, and edges into don't-ask-opinion,=.

Comment: abdul, instead of taking offense, why not just edit your own question to make it more easily understood? Your goal here is to get useful answers, and that seems like the easiest way--to write a question that other people will immediately follow. You asked whether you can apply for insurance, which you say in comments is not the real question. Why not edit the actual question description to read, "Can I use Allianz travel insurance at a hospital to cover my costs, or will they only reimburse me after I pay with my own funds?" That seems to be your real question.

Comment: @abdul of course not, there are many who offer direct billing, Ping An, Europeiska, PICC is just a few more, but in fact most companies have this offer.